# Prove that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $C(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G, o)$ be a group and $a\in G$. Prove that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $C(a)$. If there exist an element $g\in G$ such that $C(g)=Z(G)$, prove that $G$ is a commutative group. Deduce that in a non-commutative group $G$, $Z(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $C(g)$ for every $g\in G$.
>
> $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $C(a)$ is the Centralizer of $a$ in $G$

We have $$Z(G)=\{g\in G : gx=xg ~~ \forall x\in G\}  $$ and $$C(a)=\{g\in G : ag=ga \} ~~~~~~(a~~ \text{is fixed in } G)  $$

EDIT

1. To show $Z(G)\subset C(a)$

Let $p\in Z(G)$, then by definition, $px=xp$ for all $x\in G$ i.e $p$ commutes with every element of $G$ then in particular, $p$ commutes with $a$ as $a\in C(a)$, i.e $pa=ap$ and that implies $p\in C(a)$

Therefore, $Z(G)\subset C(a)$ for all $a\in G$

2. To show $Z(G)$ is non-empty
   As $ex=xe$,    $e$ being the identity element in $G$. Then $e\in Z(G)$. So $Z(G)$ is non-empty.
3. To show closer property

Let $g_1,g_2\in Z(G)$ then $g_1x=xg_1, g_2x=xg_2$ for all $x\in G$ Then $(g_1g_2)x=g_1(g_2x)=g_1(xg_2)=(g_1x)g_2=x(g_1g_2)$ in implies $g_1g_2\in Z(G)$ How to go further.

Comment: There are several parts here. Each of them is a pretty direct application of the definitions, so which part is giving you problems?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Please provide me the solution of the 1st part and hints of the other two.

Comment: No, I think it way better of you do the first part yourself. There is no trick to it.

Comment: What you need to do first is to show $Z(G)\subseteq C(a)$. Pick an arbitrary element in $Z(G)$ and show that it commute with $a$ by using definition.

Comment: I have edited for the 1st part of the question. Please correct me.

Comment: $Z(G) = \cap_{a \in G} C(a)$

Comment: @AlanWang Please correct me and help me. I have edited above.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $g\in C(g)$.
Since $C(g)=Z(G)$, $g\in Z(G)$.
By definition of $Z(G)$, $xg=gx$ for all $x\in G$, which means $x\in C(g)$ for all $x\in G$.
Thus $G=C(g)=Z(G)$.
Since $G=Z(G)$, we can conclude that $G$ is Abelian (or commutative)

After you have completed this part, you just take the contrapositive of this result (($p \implies q)\iff(\neg q\implies\neg p)$

For your updated answer, it just suffices to show that $Z(G)\subseteq C(a)$ since the center of a group $G$ is always subgroup of $G$. So if $Z(G)\subseteq C(a)$, automatically $Z(G)\leq C(a)$.

Comment: I have proved $Z(G)\subseteq C(a)$. Please comment whether it is correct. If I want to show that $Z(G)\leq  C(a)$ using the property of subgroup as I started, please help me to complete the proof.

Comment: @rama_ran https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Group_is_Subgroup/Proof_1

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the webpage, they have shown $Z(G)≤G. $ But I have to show $Z(G)\leq  C(a)$. How to modify the proof.

Comment: @rama_ran What is your definition for subgroup?

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup of a group $(G, o)$ if H is non-empty subset of G and H is a group under the same $o$.

Comment: @rama_ran Now $K\subseteq H \leq G$, You proved that $K\leq G$, so $K$ itself is a group. So it is clear that $K\leq H$.

Comment: Very sorry to say that I am unable to see $K\leq H$ without prove mathematically. I am not very strong in the subject.

Comment: @rama_ran Now $(H,circ)$ is a group and you have $K\subset H$ and $(K,\circ)$ itself is also a group. So by definition of subgroup, it is clear that $K \leq H$.

Comment: @AjanWang It is true. I understand. Please help also for remaining two parts.

Comment: @rama_ran I have answered them.